# MFC folder browser IFileOpenDialog

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

i'm trying to create a simple MFC folder browser and look for answers in MSDN and here as well:
this is my code so far:

```
void CAddFilterDlg::OnBnClickedAddDll()
{
    CFileDialog dlg(TRUE/*bOpenFileDialog*/, NULL, NULL, OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT , NULL, NULL, 0, TRUE/*bVistaStyle*/);
    CString folderPath = dlg.GetFolderPath();
    IFileOpenDialog * openDlg = dlg.GetIFileOpenDialog();
    if ( openDlg != NULL )
    {
       openDlg->SetOptions(FOS_PICKFOLDERS);
       openDlg->Release();
    }

dlg.DoModal();
}
```

the errors i'm getting are:

> 1. pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed ( this is for  openDlg)
> 2. identifier "FOS_PICKFOLDERS" is undefined

i'm working on visual studio 2010, win7

Comment: Where is openDlgPtr? I cannot see in the code snippet. "FOS_PICKFOLDERS" is defined in ShObjIdl.h , make sure that you have it included

Comment: i'll fix that sorry openDlg instead of openDlgPtr. i added #include "ShObjIdl.h" it is still not recognized

Comment: You are not setting the target window version (_WIN32_WINNT) macro properly.  IFileOpenDialog is only available in 0x600 and up.

Comment: Is your project build defined for Vista? What version of the SDK you are using?

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a bit outdated question but I recently had the same problem and also struggled to find a simple and easy-to-use solution.

I found this CFileBrowser-like class to be a very effective and simple solution to this problem:

```
CFolderPickerDialog FolderSelectDialog(theApp.xAM->GetExportPath().c_str(),NULL,this);

if (FolderSelectDialog.DoModal() == IDOK)
{
    CString cBuff = FolderSelectDialog.GetPathName();

    std::wstring wsPath = std::wstring(cBuff);

    theApp.xAM->SetExportPath(wsPath);

    CEditExportFolderPath.SetWindowTextW(cBuff);
}
```